# React Native throwing errors only on mobile

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I made an app on react native, and for now, it is just text input and a few tabs. When I test it on the snack expo editor, it works fine, but when I run it on mobile (Andriod), it throws an error saying `Attempting to change the getter on an unconfigurable property`. It seems to be coming from react-navigation. Does anyone know what is the problem? Any help would be appreciated.

Link: https://snack.expo.dev/@oofcraft/code-app

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you're right, it's a react navigation error.
the problem lies in package.json, in your dependency versions, where there is a mismatch.

you have `"react-navigation": "4.2.0",`, but you have `"@react-navigation/native": "^6.0.2",`

react navigation is running the 4.x version, while @react-navigation/native is running 6.x version. you'll have to update your react-navigation version to the 6.x version, as many things have been radically changed from 4.x to 6.x, and 4.x is no longer supported.

few things that you'll need to change:

- replace createAppContainer with NavigationContainer
- change imports: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/5.x/upgrading-from-4.x/#package-names

there are a few other things you'll find in the docs.

Comment: I did that, but now it says `Text strings must be rendered within a <Text> component only on mobile, but it works fine on the site. Problem is, it is not giving me the location of the error, do you know what could be going on? Thanks for the previous help. New Link: https://snack.expo.dev/@oofcraft/e3172d

Comment: 2 things need to be changed: 1. in the tabscreen.js, remove the navigation container, you already have a navigation container in the app.js. multiple navigation containers create issues. 2. in homescreen.js, the 'go to menu' text in the touchable opacity needs to be put inside a text component.  put a text tag inside the touchable opacity, and put the text inside the text tag